# How to display html in Thymeleaf that contains inline style with quotes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I've some html styled text that I want to display in the Thymeleaf template. To display the html, I'm using `th:utext="${myVariable}"`, however, I'm getting an error:

`Element type "span" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`

It's may be because the html looks like this:

```
<p><span style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);background-color: rgb
(255,255,255);font-size: 14px;font-family: -apple-system,
BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto
Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol",
"Noto Color Emoji;">This is my styled text.</span>&nbsp;</p>
```

As you can see, it has inline styles that are contained with "", so thymeleaf is unable to process it. Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: All of that style info should be placed in a CSS class, and not used inline. Then you can just use `th:text="${myVariable}"` for `"This is my styled text"` instead of `utext` which is a security risk if it is handling user-provided (or otherwise unsafe) content. Is there a reason why you need the styles to be inline?

Comment: Also, I cannot recreate your issue. If I do use inline styles and `utext` (NOT recommended!), then Thymeleaf renders the data correctly - the Java String has all of the double-quotes escaped (`\"`).

Comment: The html comes with inline styles and it is stored as is in the database. The (HTML) string is held without escaping the quotes in the kotlin string, and if I try to render that html using utext, then it fails.

Comment: That HTML is wrong to begin with... there is no closing quote around the font-face `"Noto Color Emoji;` (just an open quote).  Regardless of that though, this problem should be fixed before being saved in the database (by using single quotes or using `&quot;` in your inline styles.  Thymeleaf will happily spit out what is in your database, but if the original HTML is invalid in the database there is nothing Thymeleaf can do about it.